# Show each value in a PHP array as an image in HTML

Tags: php, arrays, explode, implode

I have a script to upload multiple images. After upload this is the logic:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    $value = $_POST['uploaded_image_name'];
    //print_r(array_values ($value));
    echo "</br>";
    $juntos = implode("-",$value); // joga no db tipo separados por - 1591455823.jpg-1591455824.jpg
    echo $juntos;
    print_r (explode("-",$juntos)); //volta o array 
}
```

This code returns to me something like:

```
1591456130.jpg-1591456132.jpg
```

and the explode

`print_r (explode("-",$juntos));`

returns:

```
Array ( [0] => 1591456130.jpg [1] => 1591456132.jpg )
```

The question is how to get these array values use them as the source for HTML images? Something like this:

```
echo '<img src="1591456130.jpg">';
echo '<img src="1591456132.jpg">';
```

Comment: I did not understand what exactly you need

Comment: hint: for loop/foreach

Comment: can you provide more clarity ? you mention that you are uploading images so I should see the $_FILES variable.

Comment: Get this `Array ( [0] => 1591456130.jpg [1] => 1591456132.jpg )` and show as each image on html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To iterate the array and print the contents as a list in the browser.

```
foreach($value as $img){
     print "<img src='$img' >";
}
```

Comment: does this answered your question ?

Comment: I think so, just let me implement and see how it goes.